# Are questions about hardware specifications (not compatibility) on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently commented on this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180639/request-about-description-regarding-cpuinfo), considering it off topic. User [EliahKagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) very politely indicated that he disagrees. The OP is asking for an explanation of what each of the fields in /proc/cpuinfo mean. In other words, asking what terms such as "cpu cores", "cpu MHz", "cache size", "fpu", "cpu family" etc. mean.

These are questions that are not in any way related to Ubuntu. They are hardware questions. They are not even specific to *nix. The same information can be found and will apply to *any* OS out there.

So, is this question on topic here? Would it not find a better home at superuser? If it is on topic, could someone explain why?

Just to clarify, if the community considers it on topic, then great. I am just trying to understand what the rules are here. I am very new to this site and spend most of my time on super user so I really do not want to step on any toes. I was just trying to help.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting question.